# Vectorization on nonconsecutive elements via index set

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

The standard template for vectorization seems to be thus:

```
#define N 100
double arr[N];
double func(int i);

for(int i = 0; i <N; i++)
    arr[i] = func(i);
```

where all of the indices are consecutively accessed.

However, I have a situation where not all `N`elements of `arr` need updation. The template I have is as follows:

```
#define N 100
double arr[N];
double func(int i);

int indexset[N];//this indexset has the indices of arr[] that get updated
int number_in_index_set;
//E.g., if I only need to update arr[4] and arr[10], number_in_index_set = 2
//indexset[0] = 4 and indexset[1] = 10

for(int i = 0; i <number_in_index_set; i++)
    arr[indexset[i]] = func(indexset[i]);
```

In this case, `Intel Advisor` reports that this loop was not vectorized because loop iteration count cannot be computed before executing the loop. In my application, this loop is executed for different subsets of indices, and for each such subset, `number_in_index_set` and `indexset[]` would change correspondingly.

I have two questions:

(1)What does it mean for the problematic loop to even be vectorized? The array indices are not consecutive, so how would the compiler even go about vectorizing the loop?

(2)Assuming vectorization is possible, as `Intel Advisor` seems to suggest, how can the loop in question be safely vectorized? The recommendation from `Intel Advisor` are thus:

> ```
> For Example 1, where the loop iteration count is not available before the loop 
>
> executes: If the loop iteration count and iterations lower bound can be calculated 
>
> for the whole loop:
>     Move the calculation outside the loop using an additional variable.
>     Rewrite the loop to avoid goto statements or other early exits from the loop.
>     Identify the loop iterations lower bound using a constant.
> For example, introduce the new limit variable:
> void foo(float *A) {
>   int i;
>   int OuterCount = 90;
>   int limit = bar(int(A[0]));
>   while (OuterCount > 0) {
>     for (i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
>       A[i] = i + 4;
>     }
>     OuterCount--;
>   }
> }
> For Example 2, where the compiler cannot determine if there is aliasing between all 
>
> the pointers used inside the loop and loop boundaries: Assign the loop boundary value 
>
> to a local variable. In most cases, this is enough for the compiler to determine 
>
> aliasing may not occur.
> You can use a directive to accomplish the same thing automatically.
> Target  ICL/ICC/ICPC Directive
> Source loop     #pragma simd or #pragma omp simd
> Do not use global variables or indirect accesses as loop boundaries unless you also 
>
> use one of the following:
>     Directive to ignore vector dependencies
>     Target  ICL/ICC/ICPC Directive
>     Source loop     #pragma ivdep
>     restrict
>     keyword.
> ```

Specifically, which of the above recommendations are guaranteed to ensure safe vectorization?

Comment: I general memory operations cannot be vectorized on non-contiguous elements. However you may be able to vectorize execution of the function foo, then store its scattered results. It depends on what your function foo does. Recently CPUs have introduced vectorizing instructions which allow gather-scatter operations, but these are quite slow. Only worth it if `foo` can be vectorized and it makes a substantial number of operations. If you want good vectorization you have to do it manually using `intrinsic`. In my experience compilers' auto-vectorization capabilities are still rudimental.

Comment: @Fabio in my case, `func` is a function that uses square root operator. What would it mean for a function (`func` in this case) to be vectorized?

Comment: The function takes an integer. What does it do with it? Is it `arr[i]=sqrt(arr[i])`?

Comment: No, it is a somewhat more complicated operation. It takes an `int i` and then performs euclidean distance between point `(x_i,y_i)` and some other globally available point `(X*,Y*)`

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do (ignore vectorization for now)? See code here: https://godbolt.org/z/7b0fiw  If not, post exactly the scalar function you want to optimize. Also, what architecture are you targeting, Haswell?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have. The Architecture is localhost: Intel x86-64. Pentium. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: There's one thing that's lackig in your question: What is the actual code that both works but fails to be vectorized? Extract a [mcve] for that!

Comment: You should modify your question posting the scalar function you want to specify the target architecture, as you have already done in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the additional comments, assuming the function you want to optimize is the following:

```
void euclidean(double x0, double y0, const double *x, const double* y,
               const size_t *index, size_t index_size, double *result)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < index_size; ++i) {
        double dx = x0 - x[index[i]];
        double dy = y0 - y[index[i]];
        result[index[i]] = sqrt(dx*dx + dy * dy);
    }
}
```

Since your target is Pentium, only SSE2 SIMD instructions are available. You can try the following optimized function (also available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TBbtUB)):

```
void euclidean_sse2(double x0, double y0, const double *x, const double* y,
               const size_t *index, size_t index_size, double *result)
{
    __m128d vx0 = _mm_set1_pd(x0);
    __m128d vy0 = _mm_set1_pd(y0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < index_size; i += 2) { // process 2 at a time
        size_t i0 = index[i];
        size_t i1 = index[i+1];
        __m128d vx = _mm_set_pd(x[i1], x[i0]);  // load 2 scattered elements
        __m128d vy = _mm_set_pd(y[i1], y[i0]);  // load 2 scattered elements
        __m128d vdx = _mm_sub_pd(vx, vx0);
        __m128d vdy = _mm_sub_pd(vy, vy0);
        __m128d vr = _mm_sqrt_pd(_mm_add_pd(_mm_mul_pd(vdx, vdx), _mm_mul_pd(vdy, vdy)));
        _mm_store_sd(result + i0, vr);
        _mm_storeh_pd(result + i1, vr);
    }
    if (index_size & 1) {  // if index_size is odd, there is one more element to process
        size_t i0 = index[index_size-1];
        double dx = x0 - x[i0];
        double dy = y0 - y[i0];
        result[i0] = sqrt(dx*dx + dy * dy);
    }
}
```

Here the load and store operations are not vectorized, i.e. we are loading `x` and `y` one by one and we are storing into `result` one by one. All other operations are vectorized.

With gcc the assembler output of the body of the main loop is below.

```
    // scalar load operations
    mov     r10, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    add     rax, 16
    movsd   xmm3, QWORD PTR [rdi+r10*8]
    movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rsi+r10*8]
    movhpd  xmm3, QWORD PTR [rdi+r9*8]
    movhpd  xmm2, QWORD PTR [rsi+r9*8]
    // vectorial operations
    subpd   xmm3, xmm4
    subpd   xmm2, xmm5
    mulpd   xmm3, xmm3
    mulpd   xmm2, xmm2
    addpd   xmm2, xmm3
    sqrtpd  xmm2, xmm2
    // scalar store operations
    movlpd  QWORD PTR [r8+r10*8], xmm2
    movhpd  QWORD PTR [r8+r9*8], xmm2
```

You could also do some loop unrolling (this is probably what a compiler vectorizer would do). But in this case the loop body is quite substantial, and probably memory I/O bound, so I do not think it would help much.

If the meaning of these functions is not clear, you can read [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).

A comprehensive discussion on vectorization is [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf). In brief, modern cpu offer vectorial registers in addition to the regular ones. Depending on the machine architecture, we have 128 bit registers (SSE instructions), 256 bit registers (AVX instructions), 512 bit registers (AVX512 instructions). Vectorizing means using these register at their full capability. For instance if we have a vector of `double` `{x0, x1, x2, …. xn}` and we want to add it to a constant `k`, obtaining `{x0+k, x1+k, x2+k, …. xn+k}`, in scalar mode the operation is decomposed in read `x(i)`, add `k`, store result. In vectorial mode, with SSE, it would look like read `x[i]` and `x[i+1]` simultaneously, add `k` simultaneously, store 2 results simultaneously. 
If the elements are not contiguous in memory, we cannot load x[i] and x[i+1] simultaneously, nor we can store the results simultaneously, but at least we can perform the two additions simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed code answer. I will go through the links. Could you briefly explain (or add it into the answer) what is means for vectorization in the context of nonconsecutive indices?

Comment: Also, `x[i+1]` and `x[i]` are not what the function should access. It should be `x[index[i+1]]` and `x[index[i]]` and so on.

Comment: Tryer, if you do not post the exact function you want to optimize, I am stabbing in the dark here. I have added some explanation on vectorization.

Comment: I am new to intrinsics, but slowly, I am able to figure out what is going on above. Do you have any suggestion to learn it faster/better? For e.g., to generate this intrinsic-based code, did you use or take help from the assembly instructions on the godbolt site? I notice that it uses the xmm0 register, for instance. Or is it practice, writing your own code, debugging, etc.?

Comment: I very rarely write assembler directly. Most of the time there is no need, the intrinsic are sufficient. AFAIK there are no tools which help you write this type of code. God bolt is useful, because it shows immediately how your code will be translated in assembler. For simple loops, writing manually it is not needed, the compiler will vectorize automatically. It is an expensive type of optimization, takes time to write. The Intel manual is the best way to learn. Or search the web for "simd intrinsic tutorials". For instance https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-intrinsics/

Comment: I corrected `x[i]` with `x[index[i]]`, also on godbolt.